# How to create multilingual posts in Facebook's new UI?

Tags: facebook-pages, localization, facebook-account

Facebook offers a language setting both for personal accounts and pages that allows writing posts in multiple languages.

In the new (now forced) UI, is there any way **to actually use it** while creating posts? Otherwise it's a fake setting!

[image: Multilingual posts' setting while editing]
[image: Multilingual posts' setting]

[image: Creating a post]

Comment: +1 I also still have `Multilingual posts` enabled, and the `Write post in another language` button is nowhere to be seen in the new UI.

Comment: I asked here too, never know: https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=218038993011156

Answer (score 3):

Facebook Creator Studio is required in order to publish multilingual posts.

Comment: True for pages, but what about personal profiles?

Comment: Yes... but it doesn't let you edit the translations. It seems to only support automated translations.

Comment: They have too many entrypoints for creating content, I already tested regular form (on FB) and Meta Business Suite, none of them allowed me to add another language. Creator Studio finally have this option, but I am wondering is it possible to put different links for each language 